# Android Bluetooth share multiple files, bluetooth crash, beacaus java.lang.NullPointerException: FileDescriptor must not be null

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I know there is a limit of open file descriptors in android os. I think the limit number is 1024 for per thread.
So, my question is : if you share beyond 1024 photo files by bluetooth, bluetooth will crash. The error log like this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-346
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051): Process: com.android.bluetooth, PID: 3051
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051): java.lang.NullPointerException: FileDescriptor must not be null
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051):        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:174)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051):        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:905)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051):        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:897)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051):        at android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor.<init>(AssetFileDescriptor.java:359)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051):        at android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(AssetFileDescriptor.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051):        at android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(AssetFileDescriptor.java:370)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051):        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:691)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051):        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1063)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051):        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:904)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051):        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:629)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051):        at com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppSendFileInfo.generateFileInfo(BluetoothOppSendFileInfo.java:188)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051):        at com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppManager.saveSendingFileInfo(BluetoothOppManager.java:274)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051):        at com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity$3.run(BluetoothOppLauncherActivity.java:170)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3051):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Anybody who can help me with this question?
I want to catch NullPointerException in BluetoothOppLauncherActivity.java, but it is useless!